# RazorEngine namespace not found in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a project with the razor engine package installed (https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine). I have multiple templates and I cannot compile some of them. The error is always the same:

> The type or namespace name 'X' does not exist in the namespace 'Y'

My project does not use MVC. Only the RazorEngine for template compiling. The templates that do not contain the reference X compile as work as expected. All the others have this problem.

If I look at the project references I can see that the reference is there with the flag Copy Local to true. Also, on the bin folder I can also see that the dll is being copied. For some reason it is not being compiled.

Anyone here in a similar situation with this RazorEngine library?

Best Regards.

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Hi @jtate. I will post the solution that I've found for this issue as an anwser.

Answer (score 0):

You must add namespace in web.config:

```xml
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="My Namespace" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score -1):

What happened to me was that some namespaces cannot be found by the RazorEngine (even though they were referenced). In my specific case I had some templates that had:

```
@using System.Linq
```

For some reason, this specific RazorEngine package does not interpret the Linq namespaces. What I did to fix it was to remove the Linq reference and replace all the Linq expressions for normal code expressions.

Also, in some other views I had some issues with project references that included other references that were not supported. This means that System.Linq might not be the only unsupported namespace.